# which implementation is better for static db connection?

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I know work with db.So i in my class have static object:

```
static private MySqlConnection conn = null;

    public static Boolean postoji(String username, String password)
    {
         conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=cs322;Uid=root;Password =; ");
        Boolean rez=false;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();...
```

In this class i have 5 mehtods,so i thinking,does is better to have this static object null,and initialization them in every method.Or have static object which is alrady created.

```
private MySqlConnection conn== new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=cs322;Uid=root;Password =; ");
```

and methods just use them.

Answer (score 0):

I would say better would be have this connection string in your `web.config` or `app.config` and read it from there instead of defining your connection string in code. So that in future if your connection string needs change you know only one place change would present as well editing config file doesn't need you to re-publish your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting all the connection string in the configuration file. Below is the code sample for putting and reading it from confile fie.

web config file

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"  connectionString=127.0.0.1"; Initial Catalog=cs322; Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Also same time i would suggest to wrap your connection within the Using block like below example.

Reading code from code behind

```
using(MySqlConnetion connection = new MySqlConnetion(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ToString()))
{
     connection.open();
     //setup and execute query
} //connection gets closed here
```

Here, once you exit the using block, the connection is closed.

Comment: Your posted code would throw error since `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"]` will return a key/value pair collection.

Comment: As well there would be another error saying `conn` is not defined in this context.

Comment: Disagree with the first one. We are passing the key value it will give us the connection string value from config.

Comment: *Disagree with the first one. ...*  really? Run your code and see for yourself instead of arguing with me. You said that cause you still not able to find the mistake you have done in that line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122009/discussion-between-dileep-and-rahul).